# iphone google reminder problem

Tags: iphone, gdata-api, gcal

I am integerating iphone app with google calendar using gdata api's.
Done with event add, delete, fetch, update

**but the reminder is not adding in calendar event**

My code is :

NSDate *anHourFromNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60];

GDataDateTime *startDateTime = [GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]
                 timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

GDataDateTime *endDateTime = [GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:anHourFromNow
               timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

GDataReminder *reminder = [GDataReminder reminder];

[reminder setMinutes:@"10"];

GDataWhen *when = [GDataWhen whenWithStartTime:startDateTime endTime:endDateTime];

[when addReminder:reminder];

[event addTime:when];

if (event)

{
   // Post the event.

NSURL *altLinkURL = [[calendar alternateLink] URL];

[service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:event
             forFeedURL:altLinkURL
            delegate:nil
            didFinishSelector:nil];
}

Using this code event is added in calendar but reminder is not appearing when I manually see in this event in google calendar

Answer (score 0):

Reminder should have an explicit setMethod: call; discussion is [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=77).